# convert chinese characters to UTF-8 in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby ODBC connector and getting a response like this

```
Yangpu Area, Shanghai.\r\n\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\r\n\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A251\x1A9\x1A\x1A
```

When I check the encoding using `str.encoding.to_s` I get it as `"ASCII-8BIT"`

I need to convert it to `UTF-8` correctly to save it in the database.

The expected result is -

```
Yangpu Area, Shanghai.
柳州博纳汽车科技有限公司
上海市宝山区安达路251号9库位
```

Things I've tried -

1. `str.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')`

This gives me -

`Yangpu Area, Shanghai.\r\n\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\r\n\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A\u001A251\u001A9\u001A\u001A`

2. `str.force_encoding('IBM437').encode('UTF-8')`

This also gave me the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Thanks for everyone's comments. Max's comments gave me a hint as to what to do.

I'm now getting the response as -
`Yangpu Area, Shanghai.\r\n\xE6\x1A\xB3\xE5\xB7\x1A\xE5\x8D\x1A\xE7\xBA\xB3\xE6\xB1\xBD\xE8\xBD\xA6\xE7\xA7\x1A\xE6\x1A\x1A\xE6\x1A\x1A\xE9\x1A\x90\xE5\x1A\xAC\xE5\x8F\xB8\r\n\xE4\xB8\x1A\xE6\xB5\xB7\xE5\xB8\x1A\xE5\xAE\x9D\xE5\xB1\xB1\xE5\x1A\xBA\xE5\xAE\x1A\xE8\xBE\xBE\xE8\xB7\xAF251\xE5\x8F\xB79\xE5\xBA\x1A\xE4\xBD\x8D`

which seems a bit better.

I tried this -

3. `str.force_encoding('UTF-8')`

Which gave me -

```
"Yangpu Area, Shanghai.\r\n" +
"\xE6\u001A\xB3\xE5\xB7\u001A\xE5\x8D\u001A纳汽车\xE7\xA7\u001A\xE6\u001A\u001A\xE6\u001A\u001A\xE9\u001A\x90\xE5\u001A\xAC司\r\n" +
"\xE4\xB8\u001A海\xE5\xB8\u001A宝山\xE5\u001A\xBA\xE5\xAE\u001A达路251号9\xE5\xBA\u001A位"
```

This looks as if some of the characters are getting decoded but not all.

Any suggestions would be of help.

Comment: Your string is broken already. You cannot convert a bunch of `\x1A` (ascii "SUB" character) to anything meaningful. Having the *original* source around could help.

Comment: Those are not Chinese characters. Those are the code point `1A` over and over again.

Comment: You probably need to configure your DB connection to either set the string encoding properly, or give you the raw bytes so that you can try to set the encoding yourself. Your input is ASCII-8BIT, which indicates it is already "raw bytes", so something is trying (and failing) to encode the string before it gets to you. It's hard to say how to fix it without knowing the actual library you are using.

Comment: Thanks Max. I had to set the option to to `enableutf=false` and I was getting the response, in what seems to me, to be a bit more correct! Have updated the question with that information

Comment: In your latest edit, you can see it still comes in as `\xE5\xB8\u001A` which (almost) matches this output `puts '市'.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').inspect` You could replace all instances of `\u001A` with `\xB8` or use pack/unpack to do this. However, you really need to figure out what's wrong with your server, like others have commented. And your Ruby file is UTF-8 when you do `"hello".encoding`?